# latest command line tools available for macos mojave?

Tags: terminal, command-line, mojave, xcode, homebrew

as by subject -- I have lost track of what the latest CL Tools are available *for Mojave (MacOs 10.14.x)*.  I have

```
pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
version: 10.3.0.0.1.1562985497
```

Are these the latest (obvs for Mojave, the very latest require MacOS 11 to install)?  `xcode-select` seems to believe they are, but `brew` complains I could get newer tools (or, alternatively it is a bug in `brew`) so I am not sure which one to believe.

What `brew` complained (execute `brew doctor` to see it):

```
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install
 
Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1.
```

Comment: How does homebrew "complain" about the version of the CLT you have installed?

Comment: It adds a warning -- but this was so long time ago that the chances of me fishing out the exact words are 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [XCodereleases](https://xcodereleases.com/) the last release of Xcode running in 10.14 is [11.3.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.3.1/Xcode_11.3.1.xip).